# Microservices dependencies in UML diagrams

Tags: dependencies, uml, microservices, endpoint, component-diagram

I want to explain how microservices depend on each other. 
Consider for example, the following case:

> The user service exposes the `user_detail` endpoint;
>
> The product service exposes the `product_item_detail` endpoint;
>
> The ordering service exposes the `make_order` endpoint.
>
> The user selects a product and places an order.

How can this be explained using UML diagrams?

I had planned to use a component diagram but I don't understand how to explain the interfaces of each service and how they relate to the interfaces of the other services. Is there a way to do this, or should a more suitable type of diagram be considered?

Comment: Are you interested in the static dependencies (endpoints exposed/consumed)? Or the dynamic interactions that you describe in the last sentence of your case?

Comment: I interested in static dependencies . thank you

Comment: Ideally you want to avoid microservices being dependend on each other at all. The whole point of microservices is to decouple your services.

Comment: @tomredfern technically speaking, OP is looking for dependencies on API interfaces, so the microservices stay decoupled: a microservice could be exchanged by an equivalent one offering the same interface, and the wiring could even be done [dynamically](https://microservices.io/patterns/client-side-discovery.html) using some service discovery

Comment: This seems a relevant question, I vote to reopen it.  The initial wording used "best diagram" and mislead to think that it was opinion-based, whereas the problem was in fact exposed in objective terms and called for an objective solution. I reworded accordingly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Microservices](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) are independently deployable components.  Therefore, using a [component diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html) appears a very good intuition:

> It specifies a Component as a modular unit with well-defined Interfaces that is replaceable within its environment. The Component concept addresses the area of component-based development and component-based system structuring (...).

In your component diagram each microservice would be shown as a separate [component](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component.html) with the stereotype [`«service»`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component.html#service).  Since microservices do not just implement an interface but expose it via an endpoint,  you should make use of [ports](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/port.html?context=components):

> Ports represent interaction points through which an EncapsulatedClassifier communicates with its environment.

Interfaces provided or required (lollipops and sockets) would be connected to ports.  The port make the difference:  without the port, lollipops and sockets could as well mean a [realisation](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/realization.html) or a [`«use»` dependency](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html#usage) to an interface classifier within a big monolith!

In the end your diagram could look somewhat like:  [image]

#### Additional thoughts:

- If you hesitate between `«service»` and `«subsystem»` stereotype, you may consider creating your own UML profile that defines a `«microservice»` stereotype.
- If in some complex diagram you do not want to show the detail of the service endpoints,  you may just use an assembly connector without socket/lollipop except where you want to put the focus.
- Similarly, if you are mainly interested in the dependency, you may just show the component and their dependency relation (since components are classifiers).
- If you think of microservices, you will inevitably think of [scaling strategies](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/the-art-of-scale-microservices-the-scale-cube-and-load-balancing), such as for example having several instances of the same service running on several containers/servers,  or heving several instances of the same microservice partition the data.  This kind of though is about deployment scenarios of the components.  You may then consider [deployment diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams-overview.html). But this goes far beyond your question.

Comment: Could you please make a similar schema but for the data flow between microservices?

Comment: @DDR Technically you'll have to chose between "object" flows and "message" flows. My first guess would be to use a sequence diagram, or a communication diagram. Both show the exchange of "messages" between objects or instances of components (i.e for a sequence diagram, the lifeline would be a microservice). I let you google for the graphical representation. Alternatively, you could open a more precise question.